# How to determine if a NULL value of a GROUPING value in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

BigQuery supports `ROLLUP`, such as:

```
WITH Sales AS (
  SELECT 123 AS sku, 1 AS day, 9.99 AS price UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 1, 8.99 UNION ALL
  SELECT 456, 1, 4.56 UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, NULL, 9.99 UNION ALL
  SELECT 789, 3, 1.00 UNION ALL
  SELECT 456, 3, 4.25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 789, 3, 0.99
)
SELECT
  sku,
  day,
  SUM(price) AS total
FROM Sales
GROUP BY ROLLUP(sku, day)
ORDER BY sku, day;
```

And we get:

[image]

My question is if there is a way to do [`GROUPING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [`GROUPING_ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in BigQuery? Yes, I know the workaround is 'clean-up the null-value before the query', but supposing there are tons of columns and I have no idea which ones have null values, is there a UDF or some other way to accomplish the `GROUPING()` concept in a BQ Aggregation?

Answer (score 2):

There might not be an off-the-shelf solution to your problem, but this is what I use when I am trying to do multiple aggregations in one sweep. Note that I use this when I -- either don't care about quantifying nulls or have already imputed nulls.

```
select concat(if(sku is null,'','(sku)'),
              if(day is null,'','(day)'),
              if(coalesce(sku,day) is not null,'','(overall)')) as agg_level,
        sku,
        day,
        sum(price) as total
from sales
group by rollup(sku, day)
order by sku,day;
```